# How do I replace a certain pattern in multiple files?

Tags: sed, replace, xml

My goal to update version number in multiple XML file like following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Component xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    enter code here
```

The version in the xml files might be different,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Component xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>27.0</apiVersion>
    enter code here
```

I tried several options like this

```
find force-app -type f -name "*-meta.xml" -exec sed -i '' -e 's/\(<apiVersion>\)\([0-9]+\.0\)\(<\/apiVersion>\)/<apiVersion>52.0<\/apiVersion>/' {} \;
```

and this

```
find force-app -type f -name "*-meta.xml" -exec sed -i '' -e '/<apiVersion>/s/\(\d\+\)/52.0/' {} \;
```

but they didn't work

Comment: How variable are your files? Wil `<apiVersion>` and `</apiVersion>` ***always*** be on the same line and ***only*** have numbers and `.` between them? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files are all as simple as you show, you can do:

```
find force-app -type f -name "*-meta.xml" \
    -exec sed -i '' -e 's|<apiVersion>[0-9]*[0-9.]*[0-9]*</apiVersion>|<apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>|' {} \;
```

Note that on Linux, that will give an error and you can use this instead:

```
find force-app -type f -name "*-meta.xml" \
  -exec sed -i 's|<apiVersion>[0-9]*[0-9.]*[0-9]*</apiVersion>|<apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>|' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works

Answer (score 4):

As usual, you really do not want to modify XML files using a line-oriented text editing tool.  XML is not a newline-delimited document format.

To update the `/Component/apiVersion` node's value in a single XML document, consider using `xmlstarlet` like so:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed \
    -N x='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata' \
    -u '/x:Component/x:apiVersion' -v '52.0' file-meta.xml
```

The XPath expression `/x:Component/x:apiVersion` will match the node that you want to update in the namespace called `x` (this is defined with `-N` to match the namespace in your document).  Ordinarily, i.e. when the XML document has no namespace, you don't have to bother with `-N` or prefixing the node names with `x:` like we've done here. The new value is given with `-v`.

You can edit several files in-place like so:

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
    -N x='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata' \
    -u '/x:Component/x:apiVersion' -v '52.0' *-meta.xml
```

Or, calling it from `find`:

```bsh
find force-app -type f -name '*-meta.xml' \
    -exec xmlstarlet ed --inplace \
        -N x='http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata' \
        -u '/x:Component/x:apiVersion' -v '52.0' {} +
```

If you would want to make the change only when the value is not already `52.0`, use the XPath expression `/x:Component/x:apiVersion[text() != "52.0"]` instead.

---

Using `xq` (an XML parser, part of `yq`, a YAML wrapper around `jq`, the JSON parser, from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```
$ xq -x '.Component.apiVersion |= "52.0"' file.xml
<Component xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
</Component>
```